# Reduced size references section

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing

I'm using Mendeley to manage the references for my thesis. Unfortunately there is a page limit and I was looking at my references as a place to gain back some space.

The issue that I am having is that all of the reference styles seem to include all fields in `Mendeley.bib`, where I only want an abbreviated author list `first author, et al`, the title and the year.

I know that I could prune the Mendeley document manually, however I was hoping that there was a more elegant solution to this.

Additionally I have the requirement that citations appear as `(D. Knuth (1990))` or similar, which has made the `abbrv` unfeasible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You haven't given us enough information to be able to help you. How are you producing your bibliography? Whether names are abbreviated is dependent on the `\bibliographystyle` you use. But leaving out other information is not really a good idea. If you have such a strict page limit, you should work on trimming the text itself not the bibliography.

Comment: @AlanMunn ok given that names are abbreviated depending on `\bibliographystyle` is there any post processing that I can do on the bibliography? `natbib` seems to do that on the citation side, is there anything on the bibliography side?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions for reducing or abbreviating the data, it may also be possible to use a smaller font.  How this might be done depends on the document class any bibliography style you're using, but you haven't provided that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressessing the question there are two parts:

- shorten the author list
- remove unnecessary parts of each
  bibliography entry.

To shorten the author list, `biblatex` allows a `maxbibnames` parameter to be fed in. This sets the maximum number of authors names which are mentioned before `et. al` is added. For example `D. Knuth et al`.

```
\usepackage[maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}
```

The second problem was to prune unnecessary parts of each entry: ISBN, URL etc.

To prune unnecessary parts of each entry: ISBN, URL, etc; `biblatex` allows for this in the `\AtEveryBibitem` command, where you can remove individual fields: `\clearfield{isbn}`.

*Note*: some elements will be lists, fields or names and the specific command for that must be used (see reference manual for biblatex).

This is the code that fixed my specific instance:

```
% Loads biblatex with clickable links from citations and the reference list, 
% with back references if the style supports them.
\usepackage[hyperref,doi,url=false,backref,style=trad-plain,maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{% Clean up the bibtex rather than editing it
 \clearlist{address}
 \clearfield{date}
 \clearfield{eprint}
 \clearfield{isbn}
 \clearfield{issn}
 \clearlist{location}
 \clearfield{month}
 \clearfield{series}

 \ifentrytype{book}{}{% Remove publisher and editor except for books
  \clearlist{publisher}
  \clearname{editor}
 }
}
```

Found on [codydune's blogspot.](http://codydunne.blogspot.com/2012/01/suppressing-bibtex-fields-for-specific.html)

The main benefit of this approach is that each `bibitem` can be pruned individually and hence is essentially an automated version of manually pruning the Mendeley bibliography database. This means that it is independent from the formatting of the bibliography and citation style and hence those can be set freely in an isolated manner (avoiding dependencies).

Comment: If you do this for all the fields, your bibliography will most likely not meet the standards for your field. Removing things like ISBN and DOI should be fine, but removing other fields such as location/address or date might not. Since this is for your thesis, you should check with your advisor if this is acceptable. Also, your question would have been much easier to answer if you had given more information on the kinds of fields you wanted to get rid of.